# How can I import data into Memgraph Cloud?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I want to import a CSV file into Memgraph Cloud. I'm using 2GB free instance.

I tried to use `LOAD CSV` for a file located on AWS S3, but Memgraph Lab returns "Query failed: Load CSV not allowed on this instance because it was disabled by a config."

Is this limitation of the free version? Which options are available for loading data into Memgraph Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Memgraph Cloud now it is possible to load file from via HTTPS connections using `LOAD CSV`:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "https://...."
```